# C# : MS Chart : SeriesCollection -> Range of the data in the worksheet

Tags: c#, mschart, excel-interop

I would like to cut & paste the data of a chart to a different place from its corresponding excel data-sheet.

How do I determine the range of a the chart data, so that Iam able to cup&paste the chart data ?

e.g.

```
Worksheet worksheet ...
Chart myChart ... 
SeriesCollection mySeriesCollection ...
---->>>  mySeriesCollection.getRange()  <<<<<------------- // this doesnt exist
```

Best,

Comment: I databind my series against some structure (like a list of lists of data XY values) and so if I wanted to get that information, I would do a LINQ query against the underlying data, not the MSChart data structure.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is a direct way. My best suggestion is to go over the series of the chart and check the Values and XValues of the series.

```
foreach (Series series in chart.SeriesCollection()){
   Range values = series.Values;
   Range xvalues = series.XValues;
}
```

You can then join all the ranges together and get the source data of the chart.